# Check click on mkannotations Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

Im making an application to show points on a map and on click redirect to a segue how can i check if user tapped at the annotation. And I dont know how to it, i've tried to use didSelectAnnotationView but not worked. I Hope someone can help me!

Here is my code! :

```
    @IBOutlet weak var mapa: MKMapView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    var obras = [Obras]()
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Obras")
    obras = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Obras]

    func criarObra(nome: String, descricao: String, endereco: String, latitude: String, longitude: String, status: String, valor: String) {
        let novaObra = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Obras", into: context)
        novaObra.setValue(nome, forKey: "nome")
        novaObra.setValue(descricao, forKey: "descricao")
        novaObra.setValue(endereco, forKey: "endereco")
        novaObra.setValue(latitude, forKey: "latitude")
        novaObra.setValue(longitude, forKey: "longitude")
        novaObra.setValue(status, forKey: "status")
        novaObra.setValue(valor, forKey: "valor")
        do {
            try context.save()
        }
        catch {
            print("Erro durante a criacao dos objetos")
        }
    }
    if obras.count == 0 {
        //Criando Obras
        criarObra(nome: "Metro Oscar Freire", descricao: "O Metro Oscar Freire e uma das novas estacoes da linha 4 amarela", endereco: "Avenida Reboucas X Rua Oscar Freire", latitude: "-23.560362", longitude: "-46.6725862", status: "Em Andamento - Previsao: Fim 2017", valor: "R$ 236,9 milhões")
        criarObra(nome: "Metro Higienopolis Mackenzie", descricao: "O Metro Higienopolis Mackenzie e uma das novas estacoes da linha 4 amarela que ficara proximo do Mackenzie na Consolação", endereco: "Avenida Reboucas X Rua Oscar Freire", latitude: "-23.548953", longitude: "-46.652404", status: "Em Andamento - Previsao: Fim 2017", valor: "R$ 381,6 milhões")
        criarObra(nome: "MASP - Museu de Arte de SP", descricao: "Museu de Arte de São Paulo Assis Chateaubriand (mais conhecido pelo acrônimo MASP) é uma das mais importantes instituições culturais brasileiras. Localiza-se, desde 7 de novembro de 1968, na Avenida Paulista, cidade de São Paulo, em um edifício projetado pela arquiteta ítalo-brasileira Lina Bo Bardi para ser sua sede.", endereco: "Av. Paulista, 1578 - Bela Vista, São Paulo - SP, 01310-200", latitude: "-23.561414", longitude: "-46.6580706", status: "Concluida", valor: "Nao Informado")
        criarObra(nome: "Mercado Municipal de SP", descricao: "Mercado Municipal Paulistano, também conhecido simplesmente como Mercadão, está localizado no centro histórico de São Paulo, capital do estado homônimo brasileiro, entre as ruas Cantareira, Comendador Assad Abdalla e as avenidas Mercúrio e do Estado, sobre uma área próxima ao rio Tamanduateí, no bairro Mercado, antiga Várzea do Carmo.", endereco: "Avenida do Estado/ Rua da Cantareira 306", latitude: "-23.5417132", longitude: "46.6291713", status: "Concluida", valor: "Nao Infomado")
        criarObra(nome: "Metro Hospital São Paulo", descricao: "O Metro Hospital São Paulo e uma das novas estações da obra de expansão da linha 5 lilas", endereco: "R. dos Otonis, 844 - Vila Clementino, São Paulo - SP, 04025-002", latitude: "-23.5764399", longitude: "-46.6712695", status: "Em construção - Previsão: Fim de 2018", valor: "R$ 64,5 milhões")

    }
    // Here is where i add the annotations to the map
    for obra in obras {
        let anotacao = MKPointAnnotation()
        let latitude = Double(obra.latitude!)
        let longitude = Double(obra.longitude!)
        anotacao.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
        anotacao.title = obra.nome
        self.mapa.addAnnotation(anotacao)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override mkmap delegate methods as this:

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
  {
    let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "annotationView")
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.init(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure)

    return annotationView
  }

  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)
  {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegue", sender: self)
  }
```

don't forget to change your class def to

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
  // your code
}
```